# Browse google drive api's service account

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I am uploading files to a service account (created using Google Cloud Console) using the Google Drive's API.

It is uploading successfully. I can enumerate them using  the API.

How can I browse those files from the Internet browser just like we view files in any other regular Google account (Drive)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to view the files from a browser with a Service Account. This account is primarily for administrate the accounts of the users in the same domain.

> Service accounts are accounts associated with a service or a project.
>   They do not belong to a user and can only be accessed programmatically
>   by the associated application.

Read more here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts#use_service_accounts_as_application-owned_accounts